# How can I stop ACL config being removed when overwriting an object in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an object (JSON file) in my s3 bucket that is fetched with some Javascript to display on a website. I set this access level by:

1. Clicking the object and going to the permissions tab
2. Edit the ACL and allow 'read' for the "Everyone (public access)" option
3. Saving changes

I also set a CORs policy at the bucket level to allow methods and access:

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Every day a python script runs to update the JSON with new data, something like this:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resources(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = 'my user key',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'my secret key',
    region_name = 'bucket-region')

s3.Bucket('bucket-name').upload_file('/local/path/file.json', 'dailyFile.json')
```

Every time the updated file is uploaded the read permission is removed and I have to go manually reset it.

Is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: After searching before asking this question, I think I found an answer after posting, of course. Is adding `ExtraArgs={‘ACL’: ‘public-read’}` to the `upload_file` method my solution?

Comment: Yes, that will make that specific object publicly accessible. Feel free to answer your own question!

Comment: High-level, here are the options for [making an object public](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/).

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the documentation more closely, I was able to answer my own question. Including the `ExtraArgs` parameter with the ACL policy allows me to upload the file correctly. The method would be:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resources(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = 'my user key',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'my secret key',
    region_name = 'bucket-region')

s3.Bucket('bucket-name').upload_file(
    '/local/path/file.json', 
    'dailyFile.json',
    ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})
```